# How to access restricted website area (permission set to 700) using a browser?

Tags: html, browser, ssh, permissions

I currently have a website on shared hosting. There is a section of the website (specifically a directory) that has its permission set to 700 (user only). I did this so the users of the website cannot access that section of the website. The users would get '405 Forbidden' error.

The problem I have now is that I'm not sure how I can access the webpages in that directory myself as an admin. I tried SSH tunneling but it does not work.

I must add that, the files in the restricted area are mostly HTML, so I need to open them by a browser.

Any ideas on how I can access those sections?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel try this:

```
 1. Login to your cPanel (if not already there)
 2. Click File Manager
 3. Click the name of the file for which you would like to change the
permissions.
 4. Select the Change Permissions link at the top right of the page.
 5. Select the permissions you would like to set for the file.
 6. Click Change Permissions
```

Here's some extra info that may help

```
Read = 4
Write = 2
Execute = 1
No permissions = 0

Write and Execute = 3
Read and Execute = 5
Read and Write = 6
Read and Write and Execute = 7
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not trying to change the permission of the files. I want to keep the permission as is (700) so that the users cannot access those files. But as an admin I need to be able to access the files. My question is that how can I access those files without changing the permission?

Comment: Ahhh I see With permissions set at (700) the owner should be able to read, write and execute if you are getting an error make sure your logged into an admin account. Other than that i'm lost for answers mate sorry.